# Invention of matrix symbols

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

Who first did use the symbol $\begin{bmatrix}   1 &   2 \\   3 &   4 \end{bmatrix}$ for a matrix and similarly $\begin{pmatrix}   1 &   2 \\   3 &   4 \end{pmatrix}$?
Why do these two conventions exist independently  to the present day?

Were whenever efforts made to unify the symbols?

Comment: See [Earliest Uses of Symbols for Matrices and Vectors](http://jeff560.tripod.com/matrices.html).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the link, it gives some insight into problem but it doesn't clarify it in reference to two most used symbols nowadays.

Comment: In "A Memoir ..", as I see the symbol is very close however a little different.. entries are additionally separated with commas.. to the second book it seems I have no access..

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've read the "A memoir ..." in one breath, it is wonderful, delicious.. I'm very grateful for providing this particular link..  Cayley surprisingly was using the symbol which is a mix of two modernly used symbols.. thank you also for telling about Cullis, who did popularize "rounded parenthesis" ? we still don't know , do you know why some people use the first symbol, others the second one ? It depends on country ? why there is no unification ? Maybe some interesting story is behind all of this.. (BTW - you said so much that you could consider also to give it as an answer )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Earliest Uses of Symbols for Matrices and Vectors](http://jeff560.tripod.com/matrices.html).

The first similar symbol seems to be the "mixed" one used by Cayley into his [“A Memoir on the Theory of Matrices”](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/108649.pdf?refreqid=excelsior:bbca73d3dad85de36b0239af2b5092b8) (1858).

A following reference is M.Bocher, [Introduction to Higher Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=3XBQm4uWkiwC) (1907), page 20-21.

The "squared parenthesis" notation is due to Cullis, [Matrices and Determinoids](https://books.google.it/books?id=LqL5rrXcY7MC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), 1st ed. 1913.

Comment: Finally I've downloaded also Boucher's book. He used double vertical lines for matrices at his book, although he mentioned also about rounded parentheses..  very interesting..